# iText 2.1.7 requires Bouncy Castle 1.38, can I use Bouncy Castle 1.47 instead?

Tags: itext, bouncycastle

iText 2.1.7 requires Bouncy Castle 1.38, but I have Bouncy Castle 1.47 to support other new libraries.

I don't want to put different versions, can I just use Bouncy Castle 1.47 with iText 2.1.7?

Comment: Do you make use of any security related iText features? If you don't, consider  the Bouncy Castle dependency optional.

Comment: Might one ask why you want to use an 8 year old version of iText [that can't be used in a commercial context](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5)? That sounds really odd.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can, because in Bouncy Castle versions >= 1.47 there were lots of changes in the API (check [this link](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Porting+from+earlier+BC+releases+to+1.47+and+later)).

The most significative change, that would not allow you to do a smooth change in your code, are the **classes and methods that had the names changed** - check the **"ASN.1 Changes"** section in the link above.

Most of these  are "base" classes and interfaces, like `ASN1Object` and `ASN1Encodable`, so changing the versions will probably make iText stop working (unless you find a version compatible with Bouncy Castle >= 1.47).

---

But that's just my guess, based on the changes made in the API (and my own experience when migrating to newer Bouncy Castle versions - although I didn't use iText). Anyway, it's worth trying and see what happens.

Comment: Check my Stack Overflow profile for my affiliation. I can confirm that this answer is exactly 100% correct. However not all hope is lost for the OP: iText 5 and iText 7 have a dependency on BouncyCastle 1.49, as you can check for yourself in the GitHub repositories. We also have a task in the iText 7 backlog to upgrade the BouncyCastle dependency to the most recent one, and we even got an offer from one of the BouncyCastle developers to do a pull request on our repository.